# Cant get Node to work with Laravel and browsershot

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, laravel-5, browsershot

I am trying to use the below package to generate pdf.

https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

I have node setup correctly.

```
C:\Users>node -v
v10.16.3
```

but I can't get it to work with Laravel and browsershots

below is the error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Process \ Exception \ ProcessTimedOutException

The process "node ^"C:^\xampp7^\htdocs^\copdev^\vendor^\spatie^\browsershot^\src/../bin/browser.js^" ^"^{^\^"url^\^":^\^"file:^\/^\/C:^\^\Users^\^\Vickram^\^\AppData^\^\Local^\^\Temp^\^\633105491-0293415001568545481^\^\index.html^\^",^\^"action^\^":^\^"screenshot^\^",^\^"options^\^":^{^\^"type^\^":^\^"png^\^",^\^"path^\^":^\^"C:^\^\xampp7^\^\htdocs^\^\copdev^\^\public^\^\pdfs^\^\example.png^\^",^\^"args^\^":^[^],^\^"viewport^\^":^{^\^"width^\^":1024,^\^"height^\^":690^},^\^"displayHeaderFooter^\^":false^}^}^"" exceeded the timeout of 10 seconds.
```

Below is the image for more info:
[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG5Qm.png)
Not sure if this is related to the incorrect path (have tried several suggestions including from some other posts).

I am trying this on windows. 
Any Direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to solve the issue by using `->noSandbox()`

Example: `Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->noSandbox()->save('example.pdf');`